# jQuery promises: Is there a reusable alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm building a web app which has a set of functions that the user may perform a few times but involve enough asynchronous actions for callbacks to get a bit out of hand.

What are realistic alternatives to `$.Deffered` and `$.when` that can be 'used' multiple times?

- I'm not looking for a full blown framework
- I don't want to use callbacks (directly)

Comment: 1) you don't have to use the rest of jQuery; it can be configured in a "no conflict" mode; 2) how else would deferred .. callbacks .. be implemented in JavaScript?

Comment: the whole point of Async programming is to have callbacks to notify the client that the action that was initiated is now completed without blocking the thread. If you dont want to notify the client, you can ignore the callback and do nothing.

Comment: I don't understand what "used multiple times" means.

Comment: asynchronous code without callbacks? that doesn't really work. The callback is always there, but you could choose to not use it if you don't need to do anything when the asynchronous task completes.

Comment: As far as I'm aware when a promise is resolved it cannot be reset/redeclared. I have a complex calendar with a 'next month' button, this can be pressed numerous times but involves a fair bit of async etc each time, hence I'd like to use deferred objects and promises.

Comment: I think you need to rigorously define what you want. If you want to perform an async action, it makes sense for that function to return a promise/deferred, or accept a callback function. If you genuinely want to repeat the action, call the function again, if you just want the (saved) result, call `.then` on the promise again. If you want to trigger all the callbacks that were previously attached to the promise, you should have been using events or pubsub, not promises!

Comment: Thanks David, yes the whole point of this question is that I know I don't want to use promises as by definition theyre single use! Do you have any good links/tips for events / pubsub?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for are events.  An example in jQuery using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
var data_handler = $({});

function get_data(new_foo) {
   // Do stuff, then send the event
   data_handler.trigger('new_data', {foo: new_foo});
}

data_handler.on('new_data', function(e, data) {
   console.log('Handler 1: ' + data.foo);
});

data_handler.on('new_data', function(e, data) {
   console.log('Handler 2: ' + data.foo);
});

get_data(1);
get_data(2);
```

Output:

```
Handler 1: 1
Handler 2: 1
Handler 1: 2
Handler 2: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are 3 such libraries:

1. [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)
2. [rsvp.js](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js)
3. [when.js](https://github.com/cujojs/when)

These libraries are not "full blown". They just implement promises.

Comment: From RSVP.js "Once a promise has been resolved or rejected, it cannot be resolved or rejected again." ?

Comment: @Haroldo - Of course. That's how the it's [defined in the spec](http://promises-aplus.github.com/promises-spec/#promise_states) (3.1.2.1. & 3.1.3.1), and that's the way jQuery's system work.

Comment: Ok perhaps my question wasnt clear enough, I'm looking for an *alternatve* to promises not libraries that offer promise functionality...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching to the promise directly, you can make a wrapper around the promise that allows a callback to subscribe to a recurring promise or Ajax call made at a set interval:

```
var cycle = function(func, interval){
    var _this = this;

    // Use jQuery's triggers to manage subscriptions
    var o = $({});
    this.publish = o.trigger.bind(o);
    this.subscribe = o.on.bind(o);
    this.unsubscribe = o.off.bind(o);

    var call = function(func){

        clearTimeout(_this.timeout);

        func().done(function(response){
            _this.publish('ajax:update', response);
            _this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                call(func);
            }, interval);
        });
    };
    call(func);

    return this;
};

var ajax_promise = function(){
    return $.getJSON('http://localhost/some/data.json');
};

var my_callback = function(response){
    // Do stuff
};

cycle(ajax_promise, 10000).subscribe('ajax:update', my_callback);
```